# GKE LoadBalancer pricing higher than expected

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

According to the gcloud pricing documentation LoadBalancers should cost `$0.025/h` or `$18/m` for the first 5 forwarding rules.

I have configured 4 LoadBalancers via Kubernetes services (`type: LoadBalancer`) with an expected cost of `$18/m` but instead am getting charged `$40+`.

Active services

[image]

Current Cost

[image]

I'm not sure if I am miss-understanding something here?